# Play simultaneously sound in C#

Tags: c#, wav

I want in the win Application (written in C#), the sound (Wav Format) play as Background Sound, and mouse over Control play small wav sound File, 
and when Click on Button, Stop Background Sound and ... .

Thanks For your guidance.

Comment: The question doesn't say what the problem is, nor how you're trying to play a sound nor anything like that. In fact it's incomplete, correct?

Comment: I Use "System.Media.SoundPlayer" for Play Wav File. and Use "PlaySync" Method.

Comment: Not like any homework I've ever had...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Windows Media Player:

reference C:\Windows\System32\wmp.dll in your project

to launch a wav file:

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
wmp.URL = "[wav file path]";

//then control the player with :

wmp.controls.play(), stop(), ...
```

for the second wav file, do the same thing with another instance of WindowsMediaPlayer etc...

you can also use Managed DirectX : [Managed DirectX Tutorial Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/mdxtutorial2.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could try look around in the System.Media namespace. There is a SoundPlayer which is able to play Wave files.

To play a wav file in a loop, you can use the following code:

```
string filename = @"C:\WINDOWS\Media\notify.wav";
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(filename);
player.PlayLooping();
```

To stop playing, you simple call Stop():

```
player.Stop();
```

Play around a bit, there's more if you need it.

Comment: Thanks, But When Mouse over Event of Button Occur, Play another Sound that cause stop Background Sound.

Comment: You can use the same SoundPlayer. Call .Stop() and set the property SoundLocation to the new wave file, and call .Play() to play it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to play each of them in a separate thread ?