# using CreateProcess to to play media in hidden window

Tags: winapi, shellexecute, createprocess, spawn

i just developed a tiny little game in textmode c++, what i actually wanted to do is that when the game starts it should spawn a media player in hidden mode and play the mp3 file, also i want to close the media player when the program closes or when i want it to, i have searched over the internet and found that CreateProcess() (included in shellapi.h) does this job, but i have seen that spawning an app using ShellExecute() is much easier but it does not let me Close it when i want it to, so i would like to have a working example code of the CreateProcess function that does the job, suppose that the media player is "C:\wmplayer.exe" and the mp3 file is "C:\1.mp3"... i have been a little successful in opening the mp3 player but couldnot play the mp3. i hope i'll get helped here. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You would be far better of using a programmatic interface linked to your application. For example look at the following questions for some pointers:

- [How to play MP3 files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428884/how-to-play-mp3-files-in-c)
- [How to play mp3 file in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732278/how-to-play-mp3-file-in-c)
- [Playing sounds with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789942/playing-sounds-with-c)

Trying to control mp3 player apps in different processes is akin to herding cats.

Comment: PLaySound() does the job for me but i would really like to know how to spawn and then terminate child processes

Comment: OK, I could write you an example of how to call CreateProcess, but I don't see how you can terminate it. How do you know that the sound clip has finished playing?

Comment: by its length, plus i want to stop it when the game returns to menu

Comment: Separate process is impractical for this. You say stop it by its length, but the process might take some indeterminate time to start up before sound starts.

Comment: umh allrite :) i give up :) but i would still like to get a short snippet on CreateProcess and terminating it. also that i used PlaySound() to play background music, but then i cant play fx sounds (like when an enemy fires) unless i stop the background music, i would like to know how can i play to sounds simultaneously, another question is that how can i link dll files to c++ builder xe? for example if i want to use some fuctions present in the c:\\windows\\system32\\wmp.dll how can i do that in borland compiler? thanks already for the support :)

Comment: link dlls with .h and .lib files

Comment: u mean i should do like #include <C:\\windows\\system32\\wmp.dll>  ??

Comment: no, you #include .h files. Which functions do you want to call?

Comment: actually i found some code on another post on this site here is the code WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
wmp.URL = "[wav file path]";

//then control the player with :

wmp.controls.play(), stop(), ...

Comment: here is the url where i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438377/play-simultaneously-sound-in-c

Comment: That looks like an ocx control. We are now way beyond the original question.

Comment: ok now we may leave that coz mciSendstring api fuction does what i need, i just got it working, the only thing i would like to know is that how do i loop a sound file in mciSendstring? and how to link the dlls :)

Comment: that's a different question. You should ask new questions. Comments aren't appropriate for asking new questions. Do you know how to accept and answer?

Comment: my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227742/repeating-sound-with-mcisendstring